# Modal View appearing half offscreen

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, viewcontroller

When I try to present a modal view controller, it functions as its supposed to, but it appears with the wrong orientation and only goes half way along the screen (only the top half of it is showing). The code seems simple enough -

```
-(void)showAboutView {

    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
    if (aboutViewController != NULL) {
        [self presentModalViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
    }

}
```

All the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation are set to "landscapeRight"

I realise I'm probably doing something really stupid, but I can't figure out what it is... any help gratefully received!

Comment: I know it's not an answer but you're not releasing your view controller - you've got a memory leak in there ;)

Comment: Thanks - I haven't pasted the entire method here, didn't think it would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

If it's showing up in the wrong orientation, I'd say that you've got an issue in your XIB file for AboutViewController.

Did you create that XIB in a different orientation than your app is currently in?  Look at the third tab on the property inspector -- is the autoresizing set up properly?

Comment: Thanks - yup, all set up same way, auto-resizing tried both yes & no. Bizarrely I can get it to work by orientating it wrongly, then rotating the modal view...

Comment: That's a start -- do you mean matching the orientation of the modal view, and then once that modal is active, rotating?